auto suggest for vuejs v2 component with external js file for script part
I am using vue.js v2, I like to separate my JS from my template.
<template>
</template>

<script src="./script.js">
</script>

Having JS code inside this script tag has some advantages to type checking and suggesting, which I don't have in an external JS file.
I have this comment which helps a little bit, but not in suggesting part.
// @vue/component
export default {
...
}

Is There anything that I can do to have that auto suggesting?

I don't think that you'll have a great time trying to have Vue2 + TS working together.
Consider using Vue3.
The v2 is EOL anyway nowadays, so a migration should be considered anyway.
Not really an answer to the topic, but people tend to cancel or postpone the migration and struggling with past issues that Vue2 had. Also, Vue embraces SFC ways of writing code quite a lot, so I have big doubts to make it work especially with v2 without going into big deep shenanigans for a maybe.
Should be feasible for v3 tho.

PS: why such a wish to separate both script and templating btw?

Having cleaner code.

Overall, I am stuck with this version for now.

@EisaRezaei cleaner code in what sense? I could understand if you wish to structure your mixins but some script part for a component should be small and localized anyway, I am not sure that deporting it elsewhere gonna help it anyhow. If you're stuck with it, I'd recommend to eat the bullet and deal with it while trying to see for a migration, your investment in time will just be better mid/long term if you try to move to Vue3 rather than figthting with Vue2. Again, you could shenanigan on Discord/Github to ask people for some weird setup but it's not worth the effort IMO.
